# How do proponents of the Prosperity Gospel interpret Matthew 6:19-21 and Luke 6:20-26?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-luke, prosperity-gospel

There is already this decent post: [What is the argument *for* prosperity gospel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/what-is-the-argument-for-prosperity-gospel) But more specifically how do prosperity theologians square what must be regular 'clobber' passages for their interpretation?

For example:

> Do not store up for yourselves treasures on earth, where moths and vermin destroy, and where thieves break in and steal. But store up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where moths and vermin do not destroy, and where thieves do not break in and steal. For where your treasure is, there your heart will be also.
>   [Matthew 6:19-21 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206)

And:

> Looking at his disciples, he said:
>
> “Blessed are you who are poor,
>       for yours is the kingdom of God.
>   Blessed are you who hunger now,
>       for you will be satisfied.
>   Blessed are you who weep now,
>       for you will laugh.
>   Blessed are you when people hate you,
>       when they exclude you and insult you
>       and reject your name as evil,
>           because of the Son of Man.
>
> “Rejoice in that day and leap for joy, because great is your reward in heaven. For that is how their ancestors treated the prophets.
>
> “But woe to you who are rich,
>       for you have already received your comfort.
>   Woe to you who are well fed now,
>       for you will go hungry.
>   Woe to you who laugh now,
>       for you will mourn and weep.
>   Woe to you when everyone speaks well of you,
>       for that is how their ancestors treated the false prophets.
>   [Luke 6:20-26 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%206)

Comment: From what I have seen people who misinterpret the Bible frequently skip over or ignore passages which do not agree with what they desire to teach.

Comment: @nickalh While you are correct, and I think this attributes to there being so many views, this seems to be a consistant theme.

Comment: @the above passage is easily explained and understood by PG adherents. The PG's understand they have heavenly bank accounts which they add to by giving in many diff. ways, on the earth. The giving adds to their heavenly account, from which they can withdraw, and this prosperity is kept off the face of the earth, where Satan can attack it and try to steal from it, therefore it is safe from worms, theft rust, etc. and can be used by the ones who put investments there at any time of need, withdrawing by faith.

Comment: @the above passage, beatitudes are explained by PG's by understanding that BECAUSE the KINGDOM has already arrived, those who are poor hungry weeping and hated can be glad because their needs will all now be met because the Kingdom is here!

Comment: @ the above beatitudes, those who are rich, wellfed, laughing happy and loved WITHOUT CHRIST can now realize they are stricken and have nothing because they have not CHRIST who is the KINGDOM, therefore they have nothing and even their laughter and wealth is the opposite with Him.

Comment: "
"What is the argument *for* prosperity gospel? But more specifically how do prosperity theologians square what must be regular 'clobber' passages for their interpretation?"  The arugment "for" PG and how they square clobber passages, is ONE and the SAME. It encompasses the WHOLE BIBLE, and EVERYTHING said in it about FINANCIAL, because the whole bible was inspired and given by the same author, who did not change His mind on this topic, from Gen. to Rev.

Comment: Which aspect of these passages do you think is a problem for the prosperity gospel? Suffering? The idea of reward in heaven? Could you explain a bit more how you think these are refutations of the prosperity gospel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And why do you worry about clothes? See how the 
>   flowers of the field grow. They do not labor or spin. 
>   29Yet I tell you that not even Solomon in all his 
>   splendor was dressed like one of these. 30If that is 
>   how God clothes the grass of the field, which is here > today and tomorrow is thrown into the fire, will he 
>   not much more clothe you—you of little faith?
>
> Matthew 6:28-30

Addressing the Matthew 6 verse, if you take an anti stuff position in v19-20,  how do you handle v28-30, above?

God clothes the grass better than even Solomon dressed Himself.  And, at a face value reading of v30, it says He will "much more" clothe us, apparently compared to the grass itself.

v18-19 is talking about storing up and treasure.  These are both qualities of the heart, and so the emphasis is on a covetous attitude, not having things.

The Luke passage is likewise more concerned with a willful blindness of heart.  It is not primarily concerned with "stuff".  This is shown by verses such as John 6:63 and Mark 10:30.  Of course, that is also its own balance--while prosperity can be seen in the NT, people should not be "money minded".  Even the late Kenneth E. Hagin, "father of the Prosperity Movement", said as such, and wrote "The Midas Touch" as a warning / exhortation against taking such preaching where it should not go.

Comment: An answer already exists regarding what is the case in favour of the prosperity gospel. I am not trying to attack the prosperity gospel here that would not be [what this site is for](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt). I am interested in how these passages are interpreted by prosperity theology.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought I was doing...  By showing that some 10 verses later the seeming opposite could be construed, you must take vv18-19 in the same dialogue as vv28-30.  The truth lies in the middle, and the fact that these are both Matthew 6 illustrates the distinction.  Unless I'm missing something, this is what I thought it showed.  You can take any passage and isolate it.  Representing the rest of the chapter is how you interpret this passage, because it must be taken in kind...

Comment: Sorry Benjamin, I think that comment was meant to go on a different answer that has since been deleted. Nevertheless I think this answer could be improved if you expanded upon a couple of things: namely what you mean by qualities/blindness of the heart.

Comment: I think Benj. is really 'getting' what Jesus means in the passage. Also, if the flowers are clothed better than Solomon, then the 'we' of the passage, 'will be clothed better than Solomon.' I think Benj. deserves way more than one vote, he was brilliant and really getting the meaning

Comment: Benj - you are getting Jesus, in these passages in my opinion and should have a lot of votes on what you wrote,...